# Reference embedded document with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

```
class Package
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :slug, type: String
  field :created_at, type: Time

  key :slug

  embeds_many :versions, class_name: 'PackageVersion'
end
```

I'm trying to find a way to reference the latest PackageVersion in the :versions embedded collection.  For both querying and accessing.

It would be nice if I could have a self-reference to an embedded document so that I could so something like...

```
embeds_one :latest_version, class_name: 'PackageVersion', via: :versions
```

My only solution so far has been to just store the id and add a class method to find the embedded one but that doesn't allow me to easily query using the latest_version.

Comment: There are no better solution, because there are no way in Ruby to search a key recursively.

Comment: What could be easier than calling the class method latest_version that you have created? You could also just index the versions collection on descending date so that you could run a query and return the first element.